# Why laravel does not change data on update?

Tags: laravel

I get some problem, method update do not change my data. Have no errors, but data does not changed... Can some one tell me what is the problem?

https://habrastorage.org/webt/5a/45/78/5a4578c4da9d0166994452.jpeg
https://habrastorage.org/webt/5a/45/78/5a4578dc690ea049532766.jpeg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you created related model something like `match` ?
then this can be working update function for you:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $match = match::findOrFail($id);
    $match->update($request->all());

    return redirect()->route('match.show', $match->id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also don't forget

```
class Match extends Model {

   protected $fillable = ['name', 'alias'];

}
```